# 'PyQt4 module not found' - Cannot use PyQt to open a GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I am very new to using PyQt4. So far, i have used QtDesigner to create the GUI windows i shall be using for my program.

However, when i run the first bit of python coding to get the user interface to appear, i get an error i cannot find a solution to.

Here's the code:

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

form_class = uic.loadUiType("HomeScreen.ui") [0]
```

All i am trying to do with this is to load a GUI, which is called 'HomeScreen.ui'.

Upon running this code, the python shell returns an error saying:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'
```

I have Python 3.5 installed, as well as PyQt v4.11.4 and PyQt5.6.

'QtGui' and 'QtCore' are both saved in a folder called PyQt4 (and PyQt5), which are both stored in the path:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages`

I believe this is where third party modules are supposed to be stored, but python can never find the module and i repeatedly get the same error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you installed `PyQt4`? Please reformate your error output with `backticks` to make it easier to read.

Comment: Looks like you have not successfully installed PyQt4. Are you sure you are running the script on the correct version of python? Did you get any error messages when you installed PyQt?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't have both PyQt4 and PyQt5 both installed to the same python (unless you compiled them yourself and statically linked everything) because the qt binaries would conflict.

Comment: @HåkenLid    i did a clean install of PyQt4 after removing PyQt5. it appeared i installed PyQt into the wrong folder. The PyQt4 module is now recognised by Python. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BrendanAbel  i did a clean install of PyQt4 after removing PyQt5. it appeared i installed PyQt into the wrong folder. The PyQt4 module is now recognised by Python. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I also work in windows and python 3,just run the execute file to install pyqt:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.6/

it works well in my environment

Comment: pyqt4 is also available:https://ftp.net-snmp.org/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/